# sql server 2008 / replacement in a field / from position /with specified width / with specified substring

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, replace

is there any function in sql server 2008 that do the below job :

i want to  replace in a field / from specified position /with specified width / with a specified substring...

how can i do that ?

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`STUFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function? It appears to meet your requirements.